# Visual Studios "Make object ID" feature not working in some solutions

Tags: visual-studio

I have loved the feature of Visual Studios (Im using VS19) "Make object ID", that can be called from e.g. the watch window by right clicking an watched object. It will automatically assign a number to that object, which then can be traced along a debugging session. However, this feature magically stopped working in only one solution of mine. It is not disabled or anything, you just click it, and nothing happens; no number is assigned. I checked out the solution again. Still not working. I have another solution, in which this feature just works fine. I compared the debugging options and (not surprisingly) they were completely the same. The main differences between the solutions in which this feature work and doesn't work is, that the one in which it doesn't work is HUGE and contains c#/cli/c++ code. The other solution is rather small and solely c#. However, there was a time, were this feature worked flawlessly, even in the big solution. I'm kind of puzzled. What has been kind of strange lately is, that Ive been generally struggling with different kinds of debugging issues in VS since one week or so. First I started having several crashes while debugging, so I temporarily disabled the property evaluation option. Then with a cleaned up solution all was fine, so I switched back to property evaluation. After that I started having issues in one subproject, not being able to see the values in the watch window (internal c++ error). When I switched to another project in that solution, it worked there. Now my beloved "Make object ID" wont do its job. If anybody has encountered similar issues, I gladly would like to receive your insight on this.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I messed up one Debugging option, when struggling with my prior debugging problems. I tried one workaround for another problem, that was to enable the "use the legacy c# and VB expression evaluators". This was working in the small solution but the enumeration was weird, not as usual with a $ symbol but with the # symbol. Unchecking this option in the tools-> debugging section, re-enabled this feature. I leave the solution here, if anybody else should stumble across this problem.